# Socket dynamic binding to reduced range

Tags: c++, c, sockets, serversocket, portforwarding

I have a C++ Server socket who runs within a virtual machine.
I have enabled the port forwarding for the port where the server socket is listening. However, due to dynamic binding I do not know on which port the communication will be done. 
The OS i have within the virtual machine accepts dynamic binding in the following range:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 
32768   61000
```

Is there a way (like a parameter to the bind/accept) in which i could specify to my server socket that he has to reduce this range to few ports ie: `[35000 35010]`

Cheers

Comment: No. You should either bind your socket to a fixed port or use a naming service or some other discovery mechanism for the clients to discover the service port. Hard to see what your proposal buys you.

Comment: that is what i was afraid to hear! :)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense. The port forwarding is based on the destination port, which is the port the server listens on. No "forwarding" is required based on the source port. Are you sure you actually enabled port forwarding? Listening ports never do dynamic binding.

Comment: Can you maybe edit the question to be more precise. Where did did you enable port forwarding? What precisely did you enable. What dynamic binding are you talking about? For the server's listening port? Or for a client's ephemeral port? How is the server's dynamic binding relevant, the server's not doing any dynamic binding. So what good would reducing that range do?

Comment: Ok... i tought that when i was accepting the connection the new socket created would be using another port... and that this was also going to be randomly generated within the range. I wanted to reduce the range to few port so that i could set up a port forwarding for all of them. Reading what you wrote I probably need only to forward the listening port. right?

Comment: @Stefano: the accepted socket has the same local port as the listening socket that accepted it. So you only need to forward the listening port, yes.

Comment: do you guys know how can i close this question without accepting the only answer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A listening server socket must be bound to a specific port in order to accept client connections.  On most platforms, you can `bind()` a socket to port 0 and it will bind to a random available port.  But it is still binding to a specific port.

You cannot bind a socket to a range of multiple ports. If you need to listen on multiple ports, you must create a separate listening socket for each port and `bind()` them individually (ie one socket on port 35000, one socket on port 35001, one socket on port 35002, and so on, up to port 35010).

You cannot bind a socket to an available port within a given range, either. You can only bind to a specific port, or to port 0. If you need to listen on an available port within a given range, you must loop your call to `bind()`, starting at the lowest port and trying each port in sequence until either `bind()` is succeessful or the range is exhausted.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question. He doesn't want to bind on multiple ports: he wants to bind to one of a restricted range of ports. Why, I don't know.

Comment: I answered the question asked: "*Is there a way (like a parameter to the bind/accept) in which i could specify to my server socket that he has to reduce this range to few ports ie: [35000 35010]*" - the answer is no, the socket can only bind to a specific port, not to a range of ports. Then I suggested how to bind in relation to ranges, if needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Even if there was  a way to bind to a range of ports, that wouldn't answer the question. That wouldn't reduce the range of source ports or have any effect on them.

Comment: There is nothing in the question about binding to multiple ports.

Comment: sorry guys, no need to warm up.. the fault it's mine. i tought that during the accept the new socket would be bound on a different port also on the server side to keep the original port only for listening and accepting other connections...

Comment: @Stefano: no, the accepted socket has the same local port as the listening socket that accepted it.